# ERR while trying to download npm packages for VSCode

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

It´s my firts time working with Visual Studio Code and I tried to install npm packages that were alredy required in a project. But a bunch of errors that I have never seen showed up.

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

I tried downloading Core-js,fsevents and chokidar but the same error showed up again and again.

Comment: It looks like all you got were warnings.  Everything may be ok. Did you try running after the warnings were finished?

Comment: After the warnings it stops itself and I have to write control + c to get out of that command